# Don't display wait cursor when console app is launching

Tags: c#, compact-framework, console-application

I've developed a small console application that essentially pings a url, records the result, restarts the phone if required and then schedules itself to run again.

The client is complaining about the "washing machine" icon being displayed (albeit for less than a second) every time the application launches.

I'm hiding the wait cursor in the first line of my main method but is there any way of preventing the wait cursor from displaying at all?

```
    static void Main()
    {
        //Hide cursor 
        IntPtr hOldCursor = SetCursor(IntPtr.Zero);

        //Ensure EventLog table is ready
        PrepareDatabase();

        tapi = new Tapi();
        tapi.TAPI_Open();

        //Ping specified URL and restart phone if required.
        PingRestart();

        tapi.TAPI_Close();

        //Set the application to run again after the ping interval has passed
        SystemTime systemTime = new SystemTime(DateTime.Now.AddMilliseconds(RegistryAccess.PingInterval));
        CeRunAppAtTime(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase, ref systemTime);
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps if you changed this to a threaded task, then use a `ManualResetEvent` to tell when the thread is done using the MRE's `WaitOne` method. I have not tested this, though, so I don't want to add this as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to disable the wait cursor, as it appears before the application runs so the application can't block it.

The only way is to code it in C or Assembly, as those languages start up very fast in comparison to .NET executables. But still, an AntiVirus program could block it for a while before it executes.

Comment: Your other choice being to write a much more complex program that stays running in the background (instead of scheduling itself to restart).  Then the wait cursor only shows the first time - when you are actually starting the app. so it would look something like this: **while(true) { Thread.Sleep(delayMS); using (tapi = new Tapi()) { tapi.TAPI_Open(); PingRestart(); tapi_TAPI_Close(); } }**